# How do I know which libraries should I add in JNI in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have reference the project of `Hello-JNI` , and it has `System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");` in the `HelloJni.java`.

But I didn't see any libraries call `hello-jni` in the `Hello-JNI` project.

The project of Hello-jni is like the follwoing picture.

[image]

And it show the description like the following:

```
/* this is used to load the 'hello-jni' library on application
     * startup. The library has already been unpacked into
     * /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so at
     * installation time by the package manager.
     */
```

**`The question 1:`**

**Why it load the `hello-jni libraries` ?? Where is the `hello-jni libraries` ?**

**`The question 2:`**

**How do I know which libraries should I add by `System.loadLibrary` if I only have .so file ?**

**`The question 3:`**

**And If I have libraries in libs/xxx.jar , It can work after I wirte `System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");`
right ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The compilation process creates .so files into `libs/architecture/` directory. They will be all included into the apk.

2) I don't think NDK libraries will be read in a directory other than "libs" (which, when creating the apk, is "renamed" to "lib" within the apk itself) or within a jar.

Comment: 1) It only has `libhello-jni.so` in `/libs/armeabi`...and **My question is how to load the libraries by using System.loadLibrary if I only have .so file ?**

Comment: `loadLibrary` prepends "lib" automatically. Also, it knows what path to look into. So `System.loadLibrary("hello-jni")` will find your library.

Comment: When you build the apk, the .so files in /libs/armeabi will be **automatically** put into the /lib directory within the apk. When you call loadLibrary, the system will **automatically** look into that directory.